# Setting a rule to keep numeric values in a particular range - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've been looking around to find some way of setting a rule in my MongoDB database so that I can store rgb values and ensure that they stay between 0 and 255, is there a way of doing this in Mongoose e.g. the schema model or will I need to do this at application level?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Okay, so I'm storing rgb values, which are values between 0 - 255, and therefore I'd like to ensure all data is between this range